# Selecting both parent and child items when querying child properties

Tags: c#, linq

In my data structures I have the following classes:

```
public partial class Item
{
    // stuff
    public int QuoteId { get; set; }
    public virtual ItemType ItemType { get; set; }
}

public partial class ItemType
{
    //stuff
    public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
}
```

What I want to do is get a list of all the ItemTypes, each of which has its Items collection populated according to a QuoteId.

So, for example if there are three item types, only two of which have items with a quote Id of 50:

- ItemType1

  - Item.QuoteId == 50
- ItemType2
- ItemType3

  - Item.QuoteId == 50

I've managed to get something close with this query:

```
r.ItemTypes.Select(x => x.Items.Where(i => i.QuoteId == CurrentQuote.QuoteId));
```

But what this gives you (as you might expect, since I'm `Select`ing on Item) is an `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Item>>`. This has the structure that I'm after but doesn't have the ItemType data.

I realise this is a dumb question, but I'm frustrated by my inability to get the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
r.ItemTypes.Where(x => x.Items.Any(i => i.QuoteId == CurrentQuote.QuoteId));
```

If you need to get all ItemTypes and only specific Items for every, you can do this:

```
r.ItemTypes.Select(x => new 
{
    x, 
    FilteredItems = x.Items.Where(i => i.QuoteId == CurrentQuote.QuoteId)
});
```

After that you need to assign `x.Items` to `FilteredItems` for every ItemType

Comment: Nope. Thanks for trying to help, but I already tried that. It gives me a list of Items. I need a list of ItemTypes. Obviously not explained myself very well.

Comment: Thanks - however, I need to get *all* the ItemTypes, regardless of whether they have Items or not. The SQL equivalent would be an left join. Sorry - I feel like I've explained myself very poorly.

Comment: If you want all item types then why you use query. Just take it!

Comment: @MattThrower I hope, new version can help

Comment: @Backs Yep, that's it. Thanks. Hadn't realised it needed to be a two step-process.

Comment: @MattThrower glad to help!

Answer (score 2):

You have to select the `Item.ItemType` property if you want the all `ItemType`s of a given `QuoteId`. You also have to use `SelectMany` to flatten the "nested" collections:

```
IEnumerable<ItemType> types = r.ItemTypes
    .SelectMany(x => x.Items.Where(i => i.QuoteId == CurrentQuote.QuoteId)
                            .Select(i => i.ItemType));
```

If you are not interested in the nested `ItemType`(don't know the logic) you can use [Backs' approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33497344/284240):

```
IEnumerable<ItemType> types = r.ItemTypes
    .Where(x => x.Items.Any(i => i.QuoteId == CurrentQuote.QuoteId));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = from itemTypes in r.ItemTypes
             where itemTypes.QuoteId equals CurrentQuote.QuoteId
             select new {itemType = itemTypes}
```